# React project cannot use the tiny-pinyin library to sort Chinese strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a Chinese sorting issue in my React application. I have tried using the `tiny-pinyin` library for pinyin sorting of Chinese characters, but it still doesn't work. I have installed the dependencies and tried various methods, but the problem persists. I need help in resolving this Chinese sorting issue.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Code Link: https://github.com/inwinter04/win11React_CN/blob/Dev/src/components/start/start.jsx

Partial code:

```js
const start = useSelector((state) => {
  var arr = state.startmenu,
    ln = (6 - (arr.pnApps.length % 6)) % 6;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
    arr.pnApps.push({
      empty: true,
    });
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < arr.rcApps.length; i++) {
    if (arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed < 0) {
      arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed = "Recently Added";
    } else if (arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed < 10) {
      arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed = "Just Now";
    } else if (arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed < 60) {
      arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed += "m ago";
    } else if (arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed < 360) {
      arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed =
        Math.floor(arr.rcApps[i].lastUsed / 60) + "h ago";
    }
  }
  
  var allApps = [],
    tmpApps = Object.keys(state.apps)
      .filter((x) => x != "hz")
      .map((key) => {
        const app = state.apps[key];
        // 在映射过程中将应用程序名称转换为拼音
        app.pinyinName = pinyin.convertToPinyin(app.name, '', false);
        return app;
      });
  
  // 然后根据拼音名称进行排序
  tmpApps.sort((a, b) => a.pinyinName.localeCompare(b.pinyinName));
  
  for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    allApps[i] = [];
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < tmpApps.length; i++) {
    var t1 = tmpApps[i].name.trim().toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    if (t1 > 64 && t1 < 91) {
      allApps[t1 - 64].push(tmpApps[i]);
    } else {
      allApps[0].push(tmpApps[i]);
    }
  }
  
  arr.contApps = allApps;
  arr.allApps = tmpApps;
  return arr;
});
```

https://img.iamdt.cn/2023/10/02/651a96ea47e9a.png
https://img.iamdt.cn/2023/10/02/651a96e1a2307.png

I'm using the `tiny-pinyin` library in my React app to sort Chinese pinyin.

I have ensured that the `tiny-pinyin` library is installed correctly and have tested pinyin conversion individually, which works fine.

I'm using `tmpApps.sort((a, b) => (a.pinyinName.localeCompare(b.pinyinName)))` for sorting.

I have printed out the data for debugging, but can't find the cause of the problem.

The issue seems to be related to sorting Chinese characters.

Code example:

```js
// My sorting code
const pinyin = require("tiny-pinyin");

// converts the application names to pinyin before sorting
tmpApps.forEach((app) => {
  app.pinyinName = pinyin.convertToPinyin(app.name, "", false);
});

// sorts based on the pinyin names.
tmpApps.sort((a, b) => (a.pinyinName.localeCompare(b.pinyinName)));
```

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Please, don't spam tags, if it's React question, it's unrelated to Vue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors , the question should contain relevant code so it could be understandable without navigating to external links. The question lacks clear problem statement, what does "not work" means exactly in your case? Any errors?

Comment: I apologize for not expressing myself clearly. I'm working on localizing a project, but the sorting for Chinese names is not working properly. All Chinese names are being sorted as #, and I want to be able to sort them according to pinyin. I added the following code to make it work, but it didn't have any effect and the Chinese names are still being sorted as #.    @EstusFlask

Comment: I see. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692875/3731501

Comment: There is a certain connection between the two, but it does not apply to this issue. @EstusFlask

Comment: Does `.localeCompare(y, 'zh-CN')` as suggested in the link not change the way it works in your case?